# Socket out-of-band data not received as OOB

Tags: python, c, sockets, raw-sockets

I have a C program that sends some data up to a python server on a remote machine. The C code connects the socket and then sends an out-of-band message followed by some data:

```
int on = 1;
fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int))
...
send(fd, msg, msg_size, MSG_OOB);
write(fd, data, data_size);
```

At the server the python code accepts the connection and then reads the OOB message and then the data:

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.PF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket_SOL_SOCKET, socket_SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.socket.bind(self.server_addr)
self.socket.listen(self.request_queue_size)
...
...
msg = csock.recv(msg_size, socket.MSG_OOB)
...
```

No data is received into msg, however, if I just call

```
msg = csock.recv(msg_size)
```

then I get the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, I mean 'out-of-band'. I think it's my brain that's out-of-bounds!

Comment: Are you checking the error codes of the syscall ? Specially `send()`

Comment: Another question: Why do you use `write()` and `send()` to send different buffers ?

Comment: The only difference between send and write is that send has flags. I don't need any flags for the second call so either function would do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found a subtle bug within the C code that was responsible for some data corruption that caused a few funny effects. So I think the socket code, on both ends, seems to be sound.